# TS2305: Module '"history"' has no exported member 'Transition'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I have recently updated my react-router and react-router-dom versions:

```
react-router@6.2.1 --> react-router@6.11.1
react-router-dom@6.2.1 --> react-router-dom@6.11.1
```

I've been using the exported member Transition from history to implement a leave warner if a page is unsaved:
`import { Transition } from 'history'`

After the the version upgrades my compiler gives me the following error:
`TS2305: Module '"history"' has no exported member 'Transition'.`

Some research didn't bring me any further so here's my question: How do I resolve this? Is there an other type that has the same purpose as Transition did?

Here's my implementation including `Transition`, that I've been using up until now:

```
import { Transition } from 'history';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from './useHistory';
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router';
import { useState } from 'react';

type Return<T> = {
setObjectChashed: (input: T) => void;
};

export function useWarnOnLeaveUnsaved<T extends { id: string | null }>(
objectCached: T,
saveFunction: () => Promise<void | null>): 
Return<T> {

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    const [lastLocation, setLastLocation] = useState<Transition>();
    const [doNavigation, setDoNavigation] = useState(false);
    const [cashed, setCashed] = useState<string | null>(null);

    const navigator = useHistory();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (doNavigation && lastLocation) {
            navigate(lastLocation.location.pathname);
        }
    }, [doNavigation, lastLocation]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!hasChanges()) return;

        const unblock = navigator.block((tx: Transition) => {
            const autoUnblockingTx = {
                ...tx,
                retry() {
                    unblock();
                    tx.retry();
                },
            };
            handleBlockedNavigation(autoUnblockingTx);
        });
        return unblock;
    }, [navigator, handleBlockedNavigation]);
```

Comment: Has a "transition" *ever* been a `history` export? For certain it is not included in `history@5` which is the version used with `react-router@6`/`react-router-dom@6`.

Comment: @DrewReese
If I check the definition of `history`in the old implementation it seems that transition was a type definition.

Comment: Also, just FWIW.... the React Router maintainers have taken the library in a direction that makes it ***much*** more difficult to directly access any history object and/or block navigation, e.g. it's become poor UX to "trap" users on a page.

Comment: You might try looking at the [useBlocker](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/a802be3a05020acdeb59340e96df1335a5122daa/packages/react-router/lib/hooks.tsx#L920-L951) or [usePrompt](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/2cd19443cb772f2b10c4858a40dc9343546c5b5f/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L1319-L1348) hooks. Again, take note of the documentation comments in-code of the non-stable-ness of these APIs.